# How to get bounds for all fractional variables at each node

Tags: cplex

When I set strong branching as a heuristic for branching, I know that the B&B algorithm returns objective function's value form a fractional variable which is selected in Strong branching. But I would like to get objective function's value (upper bound and lower bound) for all fractional variables at each node. For example, there are 10 fractional variables at one node and I would like to get upper and lower bound (objective function) for all 10 variables.
I know that the full strong branching compute all variables at each node. Can I get this information (objective functions' value for each variable at each node) through callbacks in C++ concert with CPLEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this information is not directly available. In the [ControlCallback](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex_ControlCallbackI.html) you have functions `getUpPseudoCost()` and `getDownPseudoCost()`. This is the closest you can get.